# Visualizing multiple time series observation

Tags: time-series, visualization, data-visualization, timeserieschart

I have multiple time-series data, plotted as shown below:

[image]

Is there a better plotting type that can show the curves of a,b,c, and d in a clearer way? Is there any other plot types where it is easy to see the "twisted" points?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two options:

1)
You do some subplots. 
[pylab_examples example code: subplots_demo.](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/subplots_demo.html)

2) 
You let all curves on the same plot. And you apply a rolling mean (also named moving average) on each curve.
[Rolling Windows](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/computation.html#rolling-windows)

One more advice.
You can limit your y axis on the graph. Space on the graph will be better optimized

> plt.ylim([0,20])